# pushing rails engine to github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rails-engines

I just finished writing my first engine, all I can find is that I should run `gem build my_gem.gemspec` to make it as a gem, what I would like to do actually is pushing it to github, but I have no idea what folders should I ignore and what to keep, is there any special command for that ?

Answer (score 0):

The engine app structure that Rails generates is designed to be deployed and mounted as a gem, so if you want to use Github as your gem's repository you can just push the entire folder structure.

For example:

```
cd path/to/engine
git commit -m "latest engine changes"
git push origin
```

will push it to Github when your Github repository has been configured as the remote origin.

Then it can be added as a gem from the main app's Gemfile:

```
gem "engine_name", github: 'github_user/engine_name'
```

Just make sure that you do not include any credentials, access keys, passwords, etc.. when pushing to Github. These should be referenced in your engine's code as ENV variables: for example:  `ENV["my_secret_credential"]` and provided by the runtime environment in production.